# Appending to a file concurrently in Go

Tags: go, file-io, concurrency

I need to write a piece of code in Go which would allow multiple go routines to write to a file concurrently.
From my current research I have seen a great suggestion on another post about utilizing a single go routine which actually deals with the file access and then have several go routines send data through a channel and essentially these appends would be sequential because a single routine would be accessing the file. This is how I have prototyped this functionality so far.

```
func ListenAndServe(ch chan dataStruct){
  
   data:= <-ch 
   // I only care about writing right now 
   // opening the file in read only I think is thread safe 
   Write(data)
}
func Write(data){// some logic to have the data written in the file}
func Read(id ){ // some logic to open the file in read only mode }
func main(){
  ch := make(chan dataStruct)
  // Would I have to start the function in its own routine like so before I begin handling 
  // the actual write/ read requests by spawning separate routines 
  // and then  ListenAndServe function would block on the channel until there is something ? 
  go ListenAndServe(ch)
  // here I would write some code for sending each request to a go routine
  
}
```

I am still new to go but If I follow this advice I found then It seems to me that the ListenAndServe function would exit as soon as it is done with the first request therefore I would have to wrap the contents of the ListenAndServe function in a for loop like so:

```
func ListenAndServe(ch chan dataStruct){
 
for {
      data:= <-ch 
      Write(data)
   }
}
```

I wanted to ask if this assumption is correct and if it realistic to accomplish this by simply blocking the routine from exiting with the infinite loop.
If anyone can give me an opinion or steer me towards a better approach I would be grateful

Comment: Not quite sure about your question, though I'd come up with something like https://play.golang.org/p/bu1acZyP6tD. Note `sync.WaitGroup` usage.

Comment: If you're asking whether you need a loop to do something an indeterminate number of times; yes, that's how it's done in most languages.

Comment: What I am trying to understand is if starting a go routine with an infinite loop for the purpose "listening" for data in a channel is a better approach to simply using a mutex and locking. Like I said I am trying to follow the advice given in the second answer here 
 and I am wondering if I have misunderstood how channels work. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981050/concurrent-writing-to-a-file)